# Casting in Java

Tags: java

If I have class `A` that have a method `foo()` and a class `B` that extends from `A` and overrides `foo()`. If I write `A a= new B();` and than I write `((A) a).foo()`- which `foo` is going to be activated? on one hand The dynamic type is `B` and `foo()` was well overridden, on the other hand- does this cast makes a to be a dynamic type of `A`?

Comment: why not write some very simple code and see for yourself?

Comment: simple could won't explain me what this casting really means in this case.

Comment: dynamic would precisely mean a would be instance of B. To proove, create a class C that extends A as B does and choose at runtime randomly if a = new B or new C. This is quite dynamic !

Comment: Explicitly casting a to be an A doesn't do anything at the method call. Generally you hold on to a subclass (or interface) in the parent object type when you don't care about the implementation and / or you might want to support other distinct implementers. By holding a B object in an A, you are just restricting yourself to A's methods.

Answer (score 5):

Try It And See.

(spoiler: the 'foo' in B overrides the one in 'A', so even if you do `((A)a).foo()` you will execute the 'foo' in B. This is common in OO languages).

Comment: Only because methods are always virtual in Java. It's not so common for C# or C++ (iirc).

Answer (score 3):

No, the instance will always stay `B`. You created `B` with **new** and casting it does not change the actual instance of the object.

Comment: So what does it really do? i never really get it.

Comment: @Nir the simplest answer to this question you just asked in a comment is not the best answer. The best answer is for you to dig out your book and learn the basics of polymorphism and you'll be able to answer this question on your own.

Comment: Casting gives you the access to the objects functions. E.g. B has a function `notInA()` and you have a object `A a = new B();` You would then have to cast to B: `((B)a).notInA()` to access this function. But San Jacinto is right, read about polymorphism.

Comment: Nothing. Upcasting is a no-op in java. edit: I tell a lie. The one place it makes a difference is field access. If A and B both declare a field x then ((A)obj).x and ((B)obj).x do no refer to the same bit object.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me to cast a value to A, which is already A..

Comment: Exactly, it does not make sense. ... well, it does only make sense if you know A only as B... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Java

Comment: @San I don't like books, and people here enjoy answering and talking, so why not? You can say it on every programming question here.."Basic" is not a curse.

Comment: @Nir But what if we're all lying to you. Or just plain wrong. Independent research is a very useful tool.

Comment: You right. Usually I check things on my own, but this wikipedia long terms scared the heart out of me. The probability that you are all lying is very small :-)

Answer (score 1):

`B.foo()` will be called. If `B` does not overwrite/implement a method, `A.foo()` will be called (if `A.foo()` is defined).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code below.
By casting `b` to `A` you restrict the access only to those public members which are declared in `A` (or any of its inherited public members), but when it comes to the implementations of public methods the casting or how the variable is declared is ignored. What matters is only the real data type of your variable (not how you declared it, but how you created it).

Instead of casting `b` to `A` you could have just as well created `b` like this: `A b = new B()`. It would have behaved the same way as when you declared it as `B` but had it casted as `A`.

When it comes to calling methods, the declaration and/or casting of objects only provides the "interface" (even if the declared/casted type is a class, think of it as an interface that contains only the public methods declared or inherited by the respective class). The implementation of the methods is provided by the real type of the data.

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        ((A) b).foo(); // real type is B
        b.fooA();// real type is B, but B doesn't override fooA() so the implementation is inherited from A
        // ((A) b).fooB(); error: `A` doesn't know about fooB
        b.fooB();
        C c = new C();
        c.foo(); // real type is C, but C doesn't override foo() so the implementation is inherited from B
        A b1 = new B();
        b1.foo(); // real type is B
        A a = new A();
        a.foo(); // real type is A
    }
}
class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    public void fooA() {
        System.out.println("fooA");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public void fooB() {
        System.out.println("fooB");
    }
}
class C extends B {
}
```

Outputs:

```
B
B
fooA
fooA
fooB
B
B
A
```